# Why do some requests in Firebug never finish loading?

Tags: firebug, http-post

I make multiple POST requests in my page, which are displayed in Firebug like they never finish loading, i.e. they have a yellow background, the throbber is displayed and there is no HTTP status code.

[image: POST requests shown in Firebug as never finishing loading]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug has some bugs related to blocked and redirected requests. These bugs cause the requests to be displayed as they would never finish loading.

### Blocked requests

[Issue 6749](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6749): Blocked requests never finish loading

In case you have a secure page (requested via HTTPS), though load insecure content (via HTTP) in it - either statically via HTML like e.g. `<img src="http://..." alt=""/>` or dynamically via JavaScript by adding these tags dynamically or making AJAX requests - you can check this via the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel). Blocked requests produce the following message:

> Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page

Here's an example of how this looks like:

[image: Messages for blocked content]

### Redirected requests

[Issue 5550](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5550): Some requests never finish loading on redirects

If your page creates requests, which are redirected to another URL, this can be tracked within the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) as a separate request. In that case you may need to enable the *Persist* button within the panel toolbar to keep the requests displayed when you revisit/reload the page. Such requests will be displayed before the redirected request:

[image: Redirected request to a website]

### Conclusion

If you get the expected response for your requests, the problem lies most probably within Firebug. You may want to compare the result with the one of the *Network* panel of the [Firefox integrated devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools) to confirm that.